# How to determine if OpenSSL and mod_ssl are installed on centos6?

Tags: linux, centos, sftp

I need to connect to a CentOS 6 server via SFTP. What are the requirements to make or accept SFTP connections?

I think I need to have OpenSSL installed, along with SSL certificates installed in both servers, but would like to know what else is required.

Comment: You don't need OpenSSL or mod_ssl for SFTP. [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) uses SSH, not SSL.

Comment: You do need OpenSSL install ...

Comment: I've certainly never had a server where SSH/SFTP worked properly with a broken SSL package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to have openssl installed, as sshd (which provides sftp) relies on it:

```
[me@lory ~]$ ldd /usr/sbin/sshd
[...]
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007ff3414d1000)
[...]
[me@lory ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64
```

The good news is that the package manager on the CentOS server will take care of that (it's almost certainly installed already; if it's not, `sudo yum install openssh-server`).  You also don't need to manually install or generate any certificates on the server; sshd will do that for itself, the first time it's started up.  The first time you connect to a new server from your client, your client will ask if you want to trust and cache the server's public key (certificate); that's the step at which you confirm you're really connected to the right server, and provides the web of trust which substitutes for certification authorities in the ssh view of the world.

You will need an ssh client on your desktop, but since you don't say what platform that it, it's hard to make a recommendation.
You may also need to enable SFTP functionality in your server's sshd, with something in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that looks like

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

but, again, check that's not already there before starting to edit configs.